# ASP.NET MVC Url routing problems

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to MVC and URL routing, and am looking for some guidance.

I would like to be able to have a URL per user, with the format:
http://www.example.com/username

So I added the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserRoute", // Route name
    "{username}", // URL
    new { controller = "Users", action = "ViewUser", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Which works great if it is the FIRST route, but it has messed up the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route.  Now when I try to visit the root page, it tries to load my UsersController "ViewUser" action with a null parameter (or with "favicon.ico" as the parameter).

If I put my new route AFTER the default route, then MVC tries to find the controller called `username` and fails because it can't find it.

Is there any way to have URLs of the form `{username}` without mucking up the regular routing system? I could probably write a custom route for every controller I have, but that seems error-prone.

Comment: You are right, routing is error-prone. Checkout http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/ if you want to completely forget about routing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alon_nativ/archive/2011/02/21/create-customize-url-with-mvc.aspx) and see if it helps. It is also creating urls with just a username on them.

Comment: This solution (which uses reflection to find all the other controllers) seems a little odd, but I suppose it should work.  I guess this particular URL scheme isn't one that the MVC team anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a constraint to the allowed controller values for the default route, instead of creating a route for each controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL
    new { controller = "controller1", action = "defaultaction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, //default values
    new { controller = @"controller1|controller2|controller3|..." }
);
```

when the controller does not match any of those it will try the next route

Comment: This might work, but it's not really any better than listing each controller individually.  I still have to remember to list each and every one, and I KNOW that in a year I'm going to add a new controller and then spend an hour battling 404's before I remember about the routing hack I used.

Comment: @Henry, it is problem of logic. Since both your routes satisfy the root url, you is the computer to understand what to load ? it just uses the first on. You could change your `UserRoute` url to be `"user/{username}"` to fix it, but that changes the url pattern you want..